# Swagger not inserting path parameter when the prefix of one controller's route is another controller's route

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

**Edit:**

It turns out that Swagger (swashbuckle) has to take the blame, it's not filling the url with the correct customerId. It should send request to some thing like */api/customers/**1**/orders*, but instead it's sending request to literally */api/customers/**{customerid}**/orders*, not filling the **customerid** with a real value.

[image]

**So, how can I make swagger to insert the real value into the url?**

**Original**:

I have a *CustomersController* and a *OrdersController*. The route of *CustomersController* is */api/customers* which is the prefix of the route of *OrdersController* (*/api/customers/{customerId}/orders*).

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> List()
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

[Route("api/customers/{customerId:int}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListOrders(int customerId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The swagger site (SwashBuckle) shows the apis correctly. However, when I try to use */api/customers/{customerid}/orders*, it returns **404**. **What should I do to configure the routing so that the api works?**

I can think of some workaround, to put ListOrders inside *CustomersController*.

```cs
public class CustomersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("{customerId:int}/orders"]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListOrders(int customerId)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

But this is not what I really want, I'd like to make the CustomersController to only deal with **customer** related stuff.

Comment: These are different prefixes. What are you sending in request?

Comment: My advice for setting routes in ASP.NET Core is to ditch the _replacement tokens_ like `[controller]` and instead to always put the full path as a literal in the route-template - and to only set `[Route("foo")]` (or `[HttpPost("foo")]`, etc) on actions (controller-methods) and never on controllers themselves. Part of the reasoning being that as a project grows you'll inevitably end-up with having 1-controller-per-action, so it works out far simpler that way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is changing the path parameter **customerId** to **customerid** (everything is now lowercase). Then the swagger (SwashBuckle) will set the path parameter into the url correctly.

```cs
[Route("api/customers/{customerid:int}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class OrdersController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ListOrders(int customerid)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```